# How did this edit got around the minimum 6 character limit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I'm referring to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/306537) edit: I understand that `voilà` is only 5 characters long. Or does `à` count as two characters? Or do removed characters count towards the limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just my perspective on it; I don't know exactly how the SE code calculates the changes (apart from having just learned that the differences are calculated after applying Markdown).

According to the Meta SE post [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/307535), in the section **Is there a minimum change threshold for a suggested edit?**:

> all suggested edits that modify the body in any way must change at least six characters in the post body. Each character added or removed counts as one towards this check.

Apparently SE calculated the removal of "wallah" as six characters, despite one of the `l`'s as being unchanged if you overlaid the texts.

Comment: To go from `wallah` to `voila`, you need to change all characters: `w`->`v`, `a`->`o`, `l`->`i`, `l`->`a`, `h` to a space _and_ remove the space that was after the old `h`. So that's 6 changes in total. I think that's how they count it.

Comment: you missed the `l` in voila?

Comment: Argh, so I did. Never mind. I do think the space makes the difference though.